# Debian 10: On a server with no default graphical.target (multiuser.target) how can I start the graphical window system?

Tags: debian, ssh, systemd, desktop-environment

I have a server with no GPU in it. Consequently the graphical environment is slow and causes the server to run slowly.

I changed the default target with systemd to be `multiuser.target`.

```
sudo systemctl set-default multiuser.target`
```

(if my memory serves me correctly)

I sometimes want to be able to login with xfce to deal with something graphical. I can run some programs with xforwarding, but sometimes I need to just log into a full GUI over ssh.

Is it possible to do this? If so how.

## Addition

See below image which shows the error message

- I recieve this same message **regardless of whether I try to login from an xfce4-terminal or a terminal such as `CTRL+ALT+F1`**

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: `startx` not working?

Comment: Talking to an X server on another machine via SSH is quite different to running an X server locally.  Which is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Panki `startx` produces this result `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the display manager you have installed, it could be either `xdm`, `gdm`, `kdm`, `lightdm`, `sddm` or something else.

E.g. `sudo displaymanager` or run `startx` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: `sudo lightdm` appears to have done something... however... how can I login to this machine and use it?

Comment: You can use Ctrl + Alt + F2 - F6 to get back to text consoles. As to *"appears to have done something"* - could you be more specific? Post a screenshot?

Comment: It didn't produce any output on the terminal. I assume the command completed successfully but I have no idea what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Ok apparently not `echo $?` reports `1`.

Comment: Can you at least start the X server? E.g. `sudo Xorg`? You should get a black screen and again use the above shortcuts to get back to your text consoles. Ctrl + C will terminate it.

Comment: `sudo xorg command not found`

Comment: You're not running the command I gave you. It's `Xorg`, not `xorg`.

Comment: I cannot do `sudo apt install xfce-desktop-environment`, however `tasksel` reports that xfce is already installed.

Comment: Ah yes, my appologies this is the output of that `(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
 If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
 and start again.
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
  at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) 
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109892/discussion-between-artem-s-tashkinov-and-user3728501).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Artem suggested, just start your display manager.

Unlike their answer, I suggest you use the service:

- `systemctl start gdm` (or some other display manager) will get you a graphical session that you can login into;
- `startx` will start X11/Xorg using your local environment and session settings;

Comment: `startx` gives me this `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`

Comment: Well, yes, you need to be on a console terminal to start a graphical session.

Comment: This links in with a conversation I was having with someone else where I explained my confusion and why I thought what I was trying to do was impossible. What is a console terminal. My guess is you mean the thing that appears when you press CTRL+ALT+Fx where x={1..7}

Comment: Even if I change to the terminal at CTRL+ALT+F1 I get the same error by the way